# Log4j does not record any log file for my project

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j

My log4j does not record any log file. I am not sure if this is a problem from the settings inside `log4j.properties` or the location of this file.

The way I built the project:

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-maven.git
```

Then modified: `.\initial\pom.xml` and added support for `log4j`:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
          <version>2.17.2</version>
          <scope>import</scope>
          <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

just before:

```
</project>
```

Added log commands to `.\initial\src\main\java\hello\HelloWorld.java` as follows:

```
package hello;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class HelloWorld {
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(HelloWorld.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.error("Application status : {} ", "start");
        Greeter greeter = new Greeter();
        System.out.println(greeter.sayHello());
        logger.error("Application status : {} ", "terminated");
    }
}
```

Then added `log4j.properties`:

```
appender.stdout.type = Console
# ... other appender properties
appender.file.type = File
# ... other appender properties
logger.app = INFO, stdout, file
# logger.app.name = com.example.app
 
# is equivalent to:
# appender.stdout.type = Console
# appender.stdout.name = stdout
# ...
appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = mylog
# ...
# logger.app.name = com.example.app
logger.app.level = INFO
logger.app.appenderRef.$1.ref = stdout
logger.app.appenderRef.$2.ref = file
```

I kept changing the location of this file to

```
.\initial\log4j.properties
.\initial\target\log4j.properties
.\initial\target\classes\log4j.properties
.\initial\target\classes\hello\log4j.properties
```

None of them have ever worked at all. I do not see `mylog` or any other log files.

The way I run the project is as follows:

```
cd initial
mvn compile
mvn package
java -jar target/gs-maven-0.1.0.jar
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Ideally the `log4j.properties` file needs to be placed inside `.\initial\src\main\resources` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with your configuration:

- As [Gopinath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71522695/log4j-does-not-record-any-log-file-for-my-project#comment126413366_71522695) remarked, the configuration file should be in `src/main/resources`. Maven will copy it to `target/classes`,
- Log4j 1.x uses the name `log4j.properties`, Log4j 2.x uses `log4j2.properties`,
- The properties configuration format is the most difficult to master. I would advise you to use any of the other format (e.g. XML, which does not require additional dependencies).

If you insist on using the properties format, here are some hints:

- every configuration requires a root logger, which is the ancestor of each logger and provides the default values for the other logger configurations. You can use the shorthand notation:

  ```
  rootLogger = INFO, stdout, file
  ```

  introduced in version 2.17.2 or the long notation:

  ```
  rootLogger.level = INFO
  rootLogger.appenderRef.$1.ref = stdout
  rootLogger.appenderRef.$2.ref = file
  ```
- The names of the appender references must match the `name` properties of the appenders:

  ```
  appender.stdout.name = stdout
  appender.file.name = file
  ```

  there is no shorthand for that.
- The `FileAppender` needs a `fileName`:

  ```
  appender.file.fileName = mylog
  ```

Comment: Just one extra question, is `log4j.properties` that was already working with log4j v1 compatible v2? I mean just by renaming a `log4j.properties` to `log4j2.properties` without an extra edit?

Comment: No, but you can use `log4j-1.2-api` and set the system property `log4j1.compatibility=true` (e.g. in a `log4j2.component.properties` file). With such a setting Log4j 2.x will read the `log4j.properties` file.